# Manipulation event cause UI Freeze or Stop Responding

Tags: wpf, touchscreen

I have used two slider control and used ManipulationDelta event to handle multitouch events. and depending on the movement of the slider some process happen. Now the issue is in my canvas movement of the object get freeze when i move my slider through touch screen.

I read somewhere, optimizing the outside code will work. but in my case i am not able to change my code outside the event.

Here is my code,

```
private void slider_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDelataEventArgs e)
{
 slider.value += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
 Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, slider.value *2);
}
```

Thanks in advance.